# Is it true that $s_{n+1} - s_n \to 0$ in a convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is it correct to say that if $s_n$ is a convergent sequence, then $s_{n+1} - s_n \to 0$. It feels right but I don't know how to test it rigorously. I am asking this because I am using this to prove a few questions.

Let $t_n$ be a sequence with:

$$t_1 = 1$$
$$t_n = \sqrt{t_{n-1} +1}$$

To find if the sequence converges to something, I used $t_{n+1} - t_n \to 0$, or $t_n \to t_{n+1}$.
Thus, setting $t_n = \sqrt{t_{n-1} +1} = t_{n-1}$, (again, not sure how to justify this rigorously), but this gives a quadratic on squaring both sides, which gives $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ as the possible value of $t_{n-1}$ where this equality happens, and thus I infer that that is the limiting value. But this seems a really bad proof. Any advice for improvement?

Comment: $t_n\to t_{n+1}$, makes no sense....

Comment: Yes. I was just trying get across the idea that in the limit the consecutive terms are equal, which is the basis for my solution to the question. I still don't know how to write it rigorously.

Comment: Actually, it is not obligatory for such a sequence to converge. But if it converges then the limits of $t_n,t_{n+1}$ should be the same.

Comment: If $s_n\to s$ then $s_{n+1}-s_n\to0$, but the converse does not hold. For an example take $s_n=\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC That was a mistake then. I meant sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, you asked if

$$t_n=\sqrt{t_{n-1}+1}$$

implies $t_n\to \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\phi$? It does not, but you are on the right track. The result you are using implicitly here is the following: if

- $x_n=f(x_{n-1},x_{n-2},...,x_{n-m})$
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$
- $f(y_1,y_2,...,y_m)$ is continuous at $f(L,L,...,L)$

then

$$L=f(L,L,...,L)$$

In your case

- $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$
- $t_n=f(t_{n-1})=\sqrt{t_{n-1}+1}$

We have to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=L> -1$ since $\sqrt{x+1}$ is continuous for all $x>-1$. To show that the limit exists and is positive (clearly greater than $-1$) we will show two things: it is increasing and it is bounded. This is enough to show that it converges to a positive number. Specifically, we will show $t_{n+1}-t_{n}>0$ and it is bounded above by $\phi$ and below by $1$. We will do this by two induction proofs:

Base case 1: For $n=1$

$$t_1\geq 1$$

Induction 1: Assume $t_{n-1}>1$. Then

$$t_n=\sqrt{t_{n-1}+1}>\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt{2}>1$$

Base case 2: For $n=1$ we have

$$t_2-t_1=\sqrt{2}-1>0$$

$$t_2=\sqrt{2}<\phi$$

Induction 2: Assume the proposition holds for some $n-1$. Then

$$t_{n}=\sqrt{t_{n-1}+1}<\sqrt{2+1}=\sqrt{3}<2$$

$$t_{n+1}-t_{n}=\sqrt{t_n+1}-t_n$$

Now, by our inductive assumption and our previous induction proof we know $1\leq t_n<\phi$. What can we say about the function $\sqrt{x+1}-x$ in the interval $[1,\phi)$? Well

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sqrt{x+1}-x\right]=\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+1}-1$$

For $1\leq x\leq 2$ this is

$$\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+1}-1<\sqrt{2+2}-\sqrt{1+1}-1=1-\sqrt{2}<0$$

We conclude on the interval $[1,\phi)$ that $\sqrt{x+1}-x$ is decreasing. Since

$$\sqrt{\phi+1}-\phi=0$$

we may conclude

$$\sqrt{t_n+1}-t_n>0$$

and we are done.

Having shown that $t_n\to L$ for some $L>0$, we may now finish the proof using the theorem stated above. We have

$$L=\sqrt{L+1}\Rightarrow L=\phi$$

We conclude

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for this. This question has been given well before this theory is introduced. Thus I am thinking there must be a way to prove this without this theory. Although this was very helpful.

Comment: What if I write $\lim t_{n-1} = \lim t_n = \lim \sqrt{t_{n-1}+1}$. Then by the fact that squaring the function inside the limit preserves the limit, 
$\lim {t_n}^2 = \lim (t_{n-1} +1)$
and then consequent algebraic manipulation I arrive at the quadratic $\lim({{t_{n-1}}^2 - t_{n-1} -1}) = 0$
Thus $(\lim t_{n-1} - \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})(\lim t_{n-1} - \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}) = 0$, thus giving the answer using the fact that $t_n >0$, which is clear from the construction of the sequence. This is assuming the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Yes, assuming the sequence is convergent it is enough to say $\lim t_n=\lim \sqrt{t_{n-1}+1}\Rightarrow L=\sqrt{L+1}$

Comment: This may very well work with $\log,$ which is concave.

Answer (score 3):

Yes $s_n - s_{n+1} \to 0$. Here is a short proof. Let $s$ be the limit (i.e. $s_n \to s$)

$$|s_n - s_{n+1}| = |s_n - s + s - s_{n+1}| \le |s_n - s| + |s - s_{n+1}| \to 0$$.

Comment: And is my final solution to the question, the one obtained by making a quadratic, correct?

Comment: @Aniruddh No, it's not correct. At least two people have already commented that $t_{n+1}-t_n\to0$ does not imply that $(t_n)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

There is a result which claims that a sequence converges iff every subsequence converges to the same value. More precisely, given a real-valued sequence $(s_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we say that $(t_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $(s_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ iff there exists a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $t_{n} = s_{f(n)}$. If we denote by $s$ the limit of the given sequence and define $f(n) := n + 1$, we may claim from the limits' properties that:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(t_{n} - s_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}t_{n} - \lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n} = s - s = 0.
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I think this is also true because any convergent sequence in Banach space is also Cauchy.

Comment: "a sequence converges iff every subsequence converges to the same value.": a much stronger result is that a sequence converges if and only if every _convergent subsequence_ has the same limit

Answer (score 1):

Some things stated also in the comments . Deducing that $t_n\to t_{n+1}$ from $t_n-t_{n+1}\to 0$ is not valid.  Also setting $t_n=t_{n-1}$ ie that $t_n$ is constant is not correct, neither and it leads you to wrong results. You may use the definition of limit to prove that $t_n, t_{n+1}$ have the same limit, if there such one.  And to prove that such a limit exists you need to prove,  if you like, that $t_n$ is bounded and monotonous .